# How to read only single command from TCP stream in every TCP read

Tags: c, sockets, tcp, microcontroller

I am a bit confused in the concept of TCP data stream.
I have several variable length commands and each command is terminated by a carriage return(\r),

```
 for eg:
command 1: C\r;
command 2: NO\r;
command 3: M1234\r;
command 4: N00\r;
```

As in the TCP this will be like a continuous data stream, like this `"C\rNO\rM1234\rN00\r"`
I have set a condition to check for carriage return(`'\r'`) and as soon as i read a carriage return, i copy my data in `local_buff` and call a function`'Transmit_Data()'` to process the
data based on the command.

Problem i am facing is in the **read function of tcp** how can i make sure that in a single read i am reading only one carriage return terminated command.
For eg:
In 1st read i may getting data `"C\r"` or `"C\rNO"` or `"C\rNO\rM1"` or any other sequence
whats the solution for this so that i will not read anything after \r in every read andonly should read reaming data if any  only in the next read.

Please look at my code if i am doing things correctly

```
while (1)
            {
                ercd = tcp_rcv_dat(cepid, cep[i].rcv_buf, sizeof(cep[i].rcv_buf), TMO_FEVR);
                /* error or fin check */
                if ((ercd < 0) || (ercd == 0))
                {
                    break;
                }
                char_posit = strchr(cep[i].rcv_buf, '\r');
                  if (char_posit != NULL)                     
                   {
                     bytes_copy = char_posit  - cep[i].rcv_buf;
                     memcpy(local_buff,cep[i].rcv_buf,bytes_copy);
                     Transmit_Data(0,cepid,i);
                     memset(cep[i].rcv_buf,0,sizeof(cep[i].rcv_buf));
                    } 
             }
```

Answer (score 4):

You can't. TCP is a stream and that's all you ever see. You'll have to read what's in the buffer and parse it yourself, coping with perhaps having more or less than an entire command at a go.

Your other option, which is nasty but easy, is just to do blocking 1 byte reads from the socket and parse as you go.

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't it be a solution to collect all the data, split them with a C function like strtok(), put it on a stack or in a buffer, and work it of?

[C Cut Strings/Char Arrays](http://www.c-howto.de/tutorial-strings-zeichenketten-stringfunktionen-zerteilen-strtok.html)